# Can we somehow rename the file that is being downloaded using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am downloading a file through puppeteer into my directory. I need to upload this file to an s3 bucket so I need to pick up the file name. But the problem is, this file name has a time stamp that changes every time so I can't keep a hard coded name. So is there a way around this to get a constant name every time (even if the old file is replaced), or how to rename the file being downloaded?

I thought of using node's fs.rename() function but that would again require the current file name.

I want a constant file name to hard code and then upload into the s3 bucket.

```
  await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: './xml'}); // This sets the directory

  await page.keyboard.press('Tab');

  await page.keyboard.press('Enter'); // This downloads an XML file.
```

Comment: Could you please add code that you use to download the file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Monitor the requests/responses to log the name of the file and rename it via Node.js
2. Use the Chrome DevTools Protocol to modify the response header

#### Option 1: Monitor the requests / response

This is the most straight-forward way to do it. Monitor all responses and in case you notice the response that is being downloaded, use the name to rename it locally via [`fs.rename`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_rename_oldpath_newpath_callback).

**Code Sample**

```js
const path = require('path');

// ...
page.on('response', response => {
    const url = response.request().url();
    const contentType = response.headers()['content-type'];
    if (/* URL and/or contentType matches pattern */) {
        const fileName = path.basename(response.request().url());
        // handle and rename file name (after making sure it's downloaded)
    }
});
```

The code listens to all responses and wait for a specific pattern (e.g. `contentType === 'application/pdf'`). Then it takes the file name from the request. Depending on your use case, you might want to check the `Content-Disposition` header in addition. After that, you have to wait until the file is downloaded (e.g. file is present and file size does not change) and then you can rename it.

---

#### Option 2: Use the Chrome DevTools Protocol to modify the response header

I'm 99% sure, that this is possible. You need to intercept the response which is currently [not supported](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191) by puppeteer itself. But as the Chrome DevTools Protocol is supporting this functionality, you can use it using the low-level protocol.

The idea is to intercept the response and change the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to your desired file name.

Here is the idea:

1. Use [`chrome-remote-interface`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface) or a [CDP Session](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#class-cdpsession) to activate `Network.requestIntercepted`
2. Listen for `Network.requestIntercepted` events
3. Send `Network.getResponseBodyForInterception` to receive the body of the response
4. Modify the body and add (or change) the `Content-Disposition` header to include your filename
5. Call `Network.continueInterceptedRequest` with your modified response

Your file should then be save with your modified file name. Check out [this comment on github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1191#issuecomment-421007646) for a code sample. As I already explained it is a rather sophisticated approach as long as puppeteer does not support modifying responses.

Comment: Got the gist of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can save the file using GUID as the filename and rename it when the download is completed.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const downloadFolder = path.resolve('./DOWNLOAD-FOLDER-HERE');

// Act like a dictionary storing the filename for each file with guid
let guids = {};

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
});

let client = await browser.target().createCDPSession();
await client.send('Browser.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allowAndName', //allow downloading file and save the file using guid as the filename
  downloadPath: downloadFolder, // specify the download folder
  eventsEnabled: true //set true to emit download events (e.g. Browser.downloadWillBegin and Browser.downloadProgress)
});

client.on('Browser.downloadWillBegin', async (event) => {
    //some logic here to determine the filename
    //the event provides event.suggestedFilename and event.url
    guids[event.guid] = 'FILENAME.pdf';
});

client.on('Browser.downloadProgress', async (event) => {
    // when the file has been downloaded, locate the file by guid and rename it
    if(event.state === 'completed') {
        fs.renameSync(path.resolve(downloadFolder, event.guid), path.resolve(downloadFolder, guids[event.guid]));
    }
});
```